# Are there equivalent to 때문에 with a positive/negative connotation?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice, difference

If I am correct, the 'Noun+때문에 / Verb+기 때문에' structure is a neutral way to express a cause. For example, 비 때문에 늦었어요 (I was late because of the rain) expresses a negative cause, whereas 여자친구 때문에 행복해요 (I am happy because of my girlfriend) expresses a positive cause.

Are there structures that express a cause:

1. emphasising that the cause is considered as negative?
2. emphasising that the cause is considered as positive?

Note: I am asking mostly because I am French Native where "a cause de" (because of) usually expresses a negative cause, whereas "grace a" (thanks to) only refers to a positive cause. I wish I could convey similar nuance in Korean.

Comment: `... 덕에`, `... 덕분에`, and `... 덕택에` for positive causes. `... 탓에` and `... 바람에` for negative causes. `... 때문에`, `-서`, and et cetera for general uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A positive one is the **덕분에 / 덕택에** construction, meaning "thanks to":

> 구 선생님 덕택에 한국어를 많이 배웠어요. => Thanks to you, Ms. Koo, I learned a great
>   deal of Korean
>
> 흥부 덕분에 제비가 목숨을 구했다. => Thanks to Hŭngbu's help, the swallow survived.

Some negative ones:

**(느)ㄴ 바람에**:

> 늦잠자는 바람에 늦었어. I was late because I slept late
>
> 취한 바람에 그는 상관과 다투었다 – under the influence of alcohol, he argued with
>   his boss

**-느라고:**

> 급하게 나오느라고 숙제를 놓고 왔어요. => Because I left home in a hurry, I left the
>   assignment behind.
>
> 뭐 하느라고 잠도 못 잤니? => Why couldn't you sleep?

There's a variation **느라니까 / 노라니 / 노라니까** – "because X, I discovered / couldn’t help Y"

> 누워서 책을 읽노라니까 잠이 오더군요 – because I was reading lying down, I found I was falling asleep

Comment: I tried to but can't fix a typo letter, from 덕텍 to 덕택.

Answer (score 4):

Another negative one is  탓: (because / by fault of).

It can be used after a verb in the form Verb+ㄴ/는 탓, or after a noun, usually Noun의 탓.  It's usually in the form 탓에 or 탓으로:

> 늦잠을 잔 탓으로 버스를 놏쳤어요
>
> 비 오는 탓에 소풍을 못 가요

Answer (score 3):

Adding to other great answers, '때문에' is more negative than positive as the linked 우리말 바로쓰기 on ['때문에'](http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=844) explains:

> 말씀하신 대로, '덕분'은 '베풀어 준 은혜나 도움'을 뜻하고, '탓'은 '주로 부정적인 현상이 생겨난 까닭이나 원인'을
> 뜻하는 말이므로, 쓰이는 맥락이 확연히 구별됩니다. 그런데 '때문'은, 그 용례를 살펴보면, 부정적 맥락에서 좀 더 많이
> 나타나기는 하지만, 특정 맥락에 한정되지는 않고, '어떤 일의 원인이나 까닭.'을 나타내는 경우에 쓰이고 있음을 알 수
> 있습니다. (용례) 그는 빚 때문에 고생을 했다.

Short summary:

> As '덕분' means a favor or help and '탓' means a cause that brought about
> a negative effect, there could be no confusion on which should be used
> for positive and negative context. On the other hand, '때문에' is used to
> describe a reason or cause for something and it is used in negative
> context a little more than in positive context.

비 때문에 늦었어요 (I was late because of the rain) could be rephrased to

> 비가 와서 늦었어요. ㅍ
>
> 비**와서** (short for 비가 와서) 늦었어요.
>
> 비**땜에** (short for 때문에) 늦었어요.
>
> 비가 오는 [바람 (See 의존명사 2)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=15128000)에 늦었어요.

여자친구 때문에 행복해요 (I am happy because of my girlfriend) could be rephrased to

> 여자친구가 있어서 행복해요. (Since I have a girlfriend, I am happy.)
>
> 여자친구 덕분에 행복해요.
>
> 여자친구가 잘 해줘서 행복해요. (Since my girlfriend is nice to me, I am happy.)

It is important to note that "비 **[탓](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=39253200)에** 늦었어요" could be used, but doesn't sound very idiomatic.